# How should I connect a humidifier to a furnace and Ecobee smart thermostat?

Tags: furnace, humidifier

I have a Goodman GMVC950704CXAB furnace connected to “humidistat HSA 100 humidity dialer” which then connects to HSA 044 then connects to humidifier water valve.

I would like to replace HSA 100 with new Ecobee smart thermostat EB-STATE5C.

Current setup

- white wire for furnace control board C terminal to HSA 100 terminal 1 and HSA 100 terminal 2 goes to HSA 044 input 24VAC terminal.
- Black wire from furnace low pressure PS1 terminal 2 to HSA 044 second 24VAC input terminal.

Note: pS1 also has a another terminal with a black wire feed by multi terminal white connector on main board of furnace.

How do I remove hsa100 wiring so function of hsa100 is performed by Ecobee . I have lots of pics but will upload if requested. Thank you for any insight.

I have already talked to Ecobee support extensively but they referred me to HVAC tech service call (surprised). Talked to Goodman manufacturer but they don’t provide support to homeowners. Thanks for any insight folks

[image]

Comment: Can your humidifier water valve be operated from 24 vac, or does it require some other voltage? How many/what colors of conductors do you have between the furnace and the thermostat location?

Comment: Greg. Water valve operates on output from hsa044 which is 24V DC

Comment: I have extra wires between furnace than ecobee thermostat. Currently using 5 (C,Rh, heat, cool and fan) I have 4 additional not currently being used

Comment: @Glabella -- can we have some photos of the wiring involved, as well as the wiring diagram for that matter?

Comment: Not easy adding pictures plus all connections listed in description. Do you have any specific questions that I can answer …